# Any useful netbeans shortcuts?

Tags: netbeans, shortcut

Anyone knows any useful Netbeans shortcuts? in eclipse for example, i used to type sysout and press CTRL+Space, anyone knows any equivalent shortcuts? Thanks in advance ;D

Comment: https://netbeans.org/project_downloads/usersguide/shortcuts-80.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called `Code Templates`. You can find them under `Tools / Options / Editor / Code Templates`. There you find a (quite extensive) list of code templates that already comes out of the box but you can also define your own.

If you type in NetBeans for example `psvm` and press than the `tab`-key NetBeans will generate

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   
}
```

for you.